# Map individual values in one dataframe with values in another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe (DF1) with two columns

```
+-------+------+
|words  |value |
+-------+------+
|ABC    |1.0   |
|XYZ    |2.0   |
|DEF    |3.0   |
|GHI    |4.0   |
+-------+------+
```

and another dataframe (DF2) like this

```
+-----------------------------+
|string                       |
+-----------------------------+
|ABC DEF GHI                  |
|XYZ ABC DEF                  |                
+-----------------------------+
```

I have to replace the individual string values in DF2 with their corresponding values in DF1.. for eg, after the operation, I should get back this dataframe.

```
+-----------------------------+
|stringToDouble               |
+-----------------------------+
|1.0 3.0 4.0                  |
|2.0 1.0 3.0                  |                
+-----------------------------+
```

I have tried multiple ways but I cannot seem to figure out the solution.

```
 def createCorpus(conversationCorpus: Dataset[Row], dataDictionary: Dataset[Row]): Unit = {
 import spark.implicits._

 def getIndex(word: String): Double = {
 val idxRow = dataDictionary.selectExpr("index").where('words.like(word))
 val idx = idxRow.toString
 if (!idx.isEmpty) idx.trim.toDouble else 1.0
 }

 conversationCorpus.map { //eclipse doesnt like this map here.. throws an error..
    r =>
    def row = {
       val arr = r.getString(0).toLowerCase.split(" ")
       val arrList = ArrayBuffer[Double]()
       arr.map {
          str =>
          val index = getIndex(str)
       }
       Row.fromSeq(arrList.toSeq)
       }
       row

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Combining multiple dataframes to create new columns would require a join*. And by looking at your two dataframes it seems *we can join by `words` column of `df1` and `string` column of `df2`* but `string` column needs an `explode` and combination later (which can be done by giving unique ids to each rows before explode). `monotically_increasing_id` *gives unique ids to each rows* in `df2`. `split` function turns *`string` column to array for an explode*. Then you can `join` them. and then rest of the steps is to *combine back the exploded rows back to original* by doing `groupBy` and *aggregation*.

Finally *collected array column can be changed to desired string column* by using a `udf` function

Long story short, following solution should work for you

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def arrayToString = udf((array: Seq[Double])=> array.mkString(" "))

df2.withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id())
  .withColumn("string", explode(split(col("string"), " ")))
  .join(df1, col("string") === col("words"))
  .groupBy("rowId")
  .agg(collect_list("value").as("stringToDouble"))
  .select(arrayToString(col("stringToDouble")).as("stringToDouble"))
```

which should give you

```
+--------------+
|stringToDouble|
+--------------+
|1.0 3.0 4.0   |
|2.0 1.0 3.0   |
+--------------+
```